# How to fix "NoSuchMethodError when calling a new static method in DownloadManager"

Tags: java, powermock, robolectric, nosuchmethoderror

I create a new static method "isDownloadAlertEnabled" in frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java.

```
public static boolean isDownloadAlertEnabled() {
    boolean isEnabled = true;
    String downloadAlert = SystemProperties.get("persist.downloadalert.enabled");
    if (downloadAlert == null || downloadAlert.isEmpty()) {
        String gms = SystemProperties.get("ro.com.google.gmsversion");
        if (gms == null || gms.isEmpty()) {
            isEnabled = true;
        } else {
            isEnabled = false;
        }
    } else {
        isEnabled = downloadAlert.equals("true");
    }
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "isDownloadAlertEnabled : " + isEnabled);
    return isEnabled;
}
```

I put the maked framework.jar in app/libs and add as library.

test1 :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class test3 {
    @Test
    public void test333() {
        System.out.println("test333 isDownloadAlertEnabled:" + DownloadManager.isDownloadAlertEnabled());
    }
}
```

result1 :

```
[Robolectric] com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.DownloadManager.isDownloadAlertEnabled()Z

at com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333(test3.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

test2 :

//getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile is a originally static method in SDK.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class test3 {
    @Test
    public void test333() {
        Context mContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        System.out.println("test333 getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile: " + DownloadManager.getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile(mContext));
    }
}
```

result2 :

```
[Robolectric] com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28
test333 getRecommendedMaxBytesOverMobile: null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

test3 :

//add PowerMockRule, and then isDownloadAlertEnabled can be called.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.powermock.*", "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*", "androidx.*" })
@PrepareForTest(DownloadManager.class)
public class test3 {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void test333() {
        System.out.println("test333 isDownloadAlertEnabled:" + DownloadManager.isDownloadAlertEnabled());
    }
}
```

result3 :

```
[Robolectric] com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28
test333 isDownloadAlertEnabled:true

Process finished with exit code 0
```

test4 :

//with RobolectricTestRunner and PowerMockRule, I can not use getSystemService.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.powermock.*", "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*", "androidx.*" })
@PrepareForTest(DownloadManager.class)
public class test3 {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void test333() {
        Context mContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        DownloadManager mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        mDownloadManager.setAccessAllDownloads(true);
        System.out.println("test333 finish");
    }
}
```

result4 :

```
[Robolectric] com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333: sdk=28; resources=BINARY
Called loadFromPath(/system/framework/framework-res.apk, true); mode=binary sdk=28

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.DownloadManager cannot be cast to android.app.DownloadManager

at com.android.providers.downloads.test3.test333(test3.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1854)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:816)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:681)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:76)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.invokeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:64)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:56)
at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:33)
at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:40)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

In conclusion,

1. In RobolectricTestRunner only, the static method "isDownloadAlertEnabled" created by me can be compiled but can not be called when running.
   But the other originally static method in SDK can be called when running.
2. With RobolectricTestRunner and PowerMock PowerMockRule, new method can be called normally, but getSystemService can not be used.

I have to use my static method and getSystemService together. How to fix all the issues?

Could anyone help me, please?
thanks a lot!

---

```
android studio 3.4.2
gradle 5.1.1
SDK 28
JAVA 8
JUnit 4.12



app build.gradle :

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.providers.downloads"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
            //returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/framework.jar')
    implementation files('libs/libcore.jar')
    //implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.9.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:4.3'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.4-rc2'
    //testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:2.0.2'

}
```